# when selecting one of the options to update the database

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have the following code to create a select dropdown:

```css
.tooltip-demo {
    position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition-property: opacity, visibility;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    position: absolute;
    top: -.75rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: #eee;
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 3.5px;
}

.most:hover ~ .tooltip,
.most:focus ~ .tooltip,
.most.active ~ .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

div.dropdown {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  div.dropdown > div.caption {
    padding: 11px 40px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  div.dropdown > div.list {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  
  div.dropdown > div.list > option.item {
    padding: 11px 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  div.dropdown > div.list > option.item.selected {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  div.dropdown > div.caption:hover,
  div.dropdown > div.list > option.item:hover {
    color: #29a4f6;
  }
  
  div.dropdown.open > div.caption {
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  }
  
  div.dropdown.open > div.list {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="tooltip-demo"><div class="most dropdown"><div class="caption"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></div><div class="list">
  <div id="resp" class="item">x</div>
  <div id="resp1" class="item">xx</div>
  <div id="resp2" class="item">xxx</div>
  <div id="resp3" class="item">xxxx</div>
  <div id="resp4" class="item">xxxxx</div>
  <div id="resp5" class="item">xxxxxx</div>
  <div id="resp6" class="item">xxxxxxx</div>
  <div id="resp7" class="item">xxxxxxxx</div>
  </div></div><button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-success tooltip" onclick="atribuirden();"> Atribuir Membro</button></div>
```

I intend that when choosing one of the options, I insert it into the database. I'll leave the js to send the data to the php:

```
function atribuirden()
{  
  var dadosajax = {
    'Resp' : $("#Resp").val(),
    'Resp1' : $("#Resp1").val(),
    'Resp2' : $("#Resp2").val(),
    'Resp3' : $("#Resp3").val(),
    'Resp4' : $("#Resp4").val(),
    'Resp5' : $("#Resp5").val(),
    'Resp6' : $("#Resp6").val(),
    'Resp7' : $("#Resp7").val()

  };

$.ajax({
    url: 'insglic.php',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: dadosajax,
success: function(data){
}
  });
}
```

But when selecting the desired option, it does not take the value for the variable to send to the php file.
The objective is when choosing one of the options to enter the value of that option in the table.

Comment: None of your code looks at all related to databases, I'm not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @DBS What I want is that when selecting one of the options, take the value of that option and insert it in the database table. I just put the html, but I'll update the question

Comment: You will need to communicate with your backend somehow, for example with AJAX. Your backend can then store the information in your database. You can not add something to the database from the frontend for security reasons. Your question lacks the information of your backend and communication code so we are unable to answer this question.

Comment: @Mark Baijens I already updated the question with ajax to communicate with the backend

Comment: By the way: The use  of `.value()` on div elements returns always an empty string because this method is not appropioate for this kind of elements

Comment: @Reporter What is the proper method for a div? Can you help me? I only intend to take the selected value and insert it into the database table

Answer (score 0):

Solution to submit the value selected in the dropdown:

```js
$("#single").select2({
  placeholder: "Selecione o Responsável",
  allowClear: true
});
        
$('#atrbbb').on('click', function() {
  $('#atrbbb1').slideToggle('slow');
});

function atribuirden()
{  
  var dadosajax = {
    'single' : $("#single").val()

  };
  console.log(dadosajax);
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Select2 CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pixeden-stroke-7-icon@1.2.3/pe-icon-7-stroke/dist/pe-icon-7-stroke.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
  
<label id="atrbbb"><i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-user"></i></label>
<div id="atrbbb1" style="display:none;">
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="atrbme" id="atrbme">
    <select id="single" class="js-states form-control" style="width: 100%;">
       <option></option>
       <option value="Teste">Teste</option>
       <option value="Teste1">Teste1</option>
       <option value="Teste2">Teste2</option>
     </select>
     <button type="button" class="btn-wide btn btn-primary" onclick="atribuirden();" arial-label="Atribuir Membro" title="Atribuir Membro"> <i class="pe-2x pe-va pe-7s-check"></i></button>
  </form>
</div>                           
                            
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```